# IOS Gradient overlay become solid color after scrolling

Tags: ios

I have a custom tableview that will be filled with dynamic objects to form a list. I am trying to set a gradient overlay on half top of my image in my cell.

I set my layout in interface.builder.

Below is my question:
- I am having issue where my gradient overlay seems to get repaint every time leading it to become a solid color overlay after scrolling up/down. Anyone have any idea how to overcome this?

Thanks!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell* )[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCellId"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableCellId"];
    }

    UIImageView *item_image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:@"cell_image"];
    NSString *url_image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", URL_SERVER_HOST, item_pic];

    [item_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_image]];

    //Currently get called when new cell is loaded
    UIView *overlay = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:@"cell_overlay"];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = overlay.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
    [overlay.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    UILabel * item_name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:@"cell_name"];
    item_name.text  = @"test text";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the gradient related code into `if (cell == nil)`, so when the cell is reused, it won't add the gradient layer again

Comment: I tried that but somehow cell is never nil, moving it in causes gradient never be called

Comment: If you create the cell using storyboard or register the nib to tableview, you can add the gradient layer in the method -awakeFromNib in the class of the cell. Otherwise you can add the gradient layer in -initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

I just set my overlay sub-layers to nil before applying the gradient. Just write below line before `[overlay.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];`

`overlay.layer.sublayers = nil;`